# Is there a `v-html` equivalent in Svelte?

Tags: web, svelte, svelte-3

I have recently taken on Svelte and I have been coding a couple of things with it.  I have been just doing

```
<script>
  let title = "Amazing title"
</script>

<h1>{ title }</h1>
```

when setting the complete value of an html element to the variable, but I would like to know if there is a better way to accomplish this such as the v-html in Vue JS

```
<template>
  <h1 v-html="title" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Amazing title"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks a ton for all of your help and have a great day!

Comment: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/html-tags

Comment: @voscausa Yeah I saw that, but I was trying to find if there is an actual html attribute for html and text (like `v-html` and `v-text`)

Comment: No there isn't, remember that Svelte is different from Vue.  It is very intentional that Svelte does not use those attribute directives like Vue does and has a completely different approach.  It is better to embrace the tools a new framework uses than trying to apply the logic of a previous one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `{@html variableName}`. So instead of `<span v-html="rawHTML"></span>`, you can do `<span>{@html rawHTML}</span>`. It is reactive if `rawHTML` changes.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything built into Svelte that is an HTML attribute providing a directive like Vue to my knowledge. But it's very easy to build your own equivalent directives using [actions](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions).

To emulate the functionality of Vue's v-html and v-text you can return an update function that changes innerHTML or innerText in a js file:

```
// html.js
export function html(node, content) {
node.innerHTML = content
return {
    update(content) {
        node.innerHTML = content
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it on the element whose contents you want to replace:

```
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import { html } from './html.js'
  let content = `<p>Content</p>`
</script>

<p use:html={content} />
```

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/51d86710a41c4e81958d2d21da2edc6c?version=3.24.1) showing a more complete example with a v-text style action as well.